# Additive characters of $\mathbb{C}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, characters

Consider $x \in \mathbb{C}_p$ with $|x|<1$ then for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ we have the characters 
$$
 a \mapsto (1+x)^a
$$
where $(1+x)^a= \exp(a\log_p(1+x))$
My question is : it's possible to extend these characters to locally analytic characters in all $\mathbb{C}_p$?

Thanks for references!

Comment: Do you mean that you want $a$ to take values outside of $\Bbb Z_p$, or do you mean that you want to take $|x|\ge1$ ?

Comment: @Lubin I mean when $a$ takes values outside Z_p

Comment: Well, the binomial formula for $(1+x)^a$ that I have given below shows that when $a\notin\Bbb Z_p$, some coefficients will be nonintegral (i.e. have absolute value greater than $1$) and in that case the whole series will presumably fail to be convergent, except on a smaller disk. This could be worth a closer examination.

Comment: @Lubin So it seems difficult to extend these characters, but exists a sort of classification of such characters $(\mathbb{C}_p,+)\to(\mathbb{C}_p,\times) $? I saw that $exp_p$ could be extended in a non-canonical way like the classical logarithm to obtain, for example, the Iwasawa logarithm. So maybe this could give some results. But really thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment, not in any sense an answer.

But you simply can not define $(1+x)^a$ that way, because for $|x|$ very nearly $1$ (in the language of the additive valuation $v(x)=-\log_p(|x|)$: for $v(x)$ very small but positive), $v(\log(1+x))$ will be negative, in other words $\log(x)$ is not even in the ring of integers of the field $\Bbb Q_p(x)$, and certainly not in the domain of any $p$-adic exponential function.

One perfectly satisfactory way of defining $(1+x)^a$ is:
$$
(1+x)^a=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom akx^k\,,\\
\text{where }\binom ak=\frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k!}\,.
$$
It’s a satisfying exercise to show that if $a\in\Bbb Z_p$, then so is $\binom ak$ for every positive integer $k$.

Another perfectly satisfactory way of defining $(1+x)^a$ is:
$$
(1+x)^a=\lim_{|n-a|\to0}(1+x)^n\,,
$$
where the values allowed for $n$ are positive integers, and the limit is taken $p$-adically.

*Please note:* You have written “$\log_p$” for the $p$-adic logarithm, but I have called this simply “log”, while when I wrote “$\log_p$”, I meant the real logarithm to base $p$, as you learn to do in high-school.

Comment: Yes I forgot to recall it, my notation for Iwasawa logarithm is with $ \log_p$